# too much recursion : leaflet polyline backboneJS

Tags: backbone.js, leaflet

I am trying to add a polyline connecting two circles in a leaflet map.
I am able to add two circles but the polyline never gets added.

I get this error:

> too much recursion    this.__updatePath.call(this);

I am using Backbone JS View and this is the code I am using:

```
 var cc = L.circle([37.3544, -121.98], 20000).addTo(map);
          var cb = L.circle([40.71, -74], 20000).addTo(map);
          var pointA = new L.LatLng(37.3544, -121.98);
          var pointB = new L.LatLng(40.71, -74);
          var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

          var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
          color: 'green',
          weight: 3,
          opacity: 1.0,
          smoothFactor: 3
          });

      firstpolyline.addTo(map);
```

I have put all this in the **render()** function.
Kindly help me.

P.S : If I print this in a normal HTML file I am able to see the polyline.